# How to Sing In a User using AWS Cognito in Kotlin Application?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, kotlin, amazon-cognito

When i try to sign in a user that I created using console in Cognito, neither of the methods override onSuccess or override onFailure of AuthenticationHandler get executed only override authenticationChallenge methods runs and I am not using MFA.

what is wrong or how should I approach to sign in a user?

```
class FacultyLoginViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var userPool: CognitoUserPool

    private var loginResultsLiveData: MutableLiveData<ScreenState<Boolean>> = MutableLiveData()
    val loginResultLiveData: LiveData<ScreenState<Boolean>>
        get() = loginResultsLiveData

    fun init(userPool: CognitoUserPool) {
        this.userPool = userPool
    }

    fun login(email: String, pass: String) {
        val user = userPool.getUser(email)
        val authenticationHandler: AuthenticationHandler = object : AuthenticationHandler {
            override fun authenticationChallenge(continuation: ChallengeContinuation) {
                Log.e("challenge_0","Challenge_0")
            }
            override fun onSuccess(userSession: CognitoUserSession, newDevice: CognitoDevice) {
                Log.e("success_0","Success")
            }
            override fun getAuthenticationDetails(authenticationContinuation: AuthenticationContinuation, userId: String) {
                // The API needs user sign-in credentials to continue
                val authenticationDetails = AuthenticationDetails(userId, pass, null)
                // Pass the user sign-in credentials to the continuation
                authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails)
                // Allow the sign-in to continue
                authenticationContinuation.continueTask()
            }

            override fun getMFACode(multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation: MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation) {

            }

            override fun onFailure(exception: Exception) {
                Log.e("error_0",exception.toString())
            }
        }
        user.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler)
    }

}
```

My dependencies are

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.16.0'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.16.0'
```